# UK London - Tenancy Agreement - 2 Months notice on fixed term end

Tags: united-kingdom, tenant, fair-housing-acts

Backstory : 1 month before my Fixed Term ends, my landlord called me and said that he would be increasing the price of property, which basically made me start looking for other properties.
After 6 days, I sent him a whatsapp message, since thats the way we usually comunicate saying that I wouldnt be renewing, this was on the 14th of april, 1 month before my tenancy agreement ends.
I called yesterday asking what to do with the flat, as in , which cleaning company he has a preference for to clean the flat, and to ask about the deposit, and he said, that since I didnt give him the 2 months notice, that I am liable for 2 extra months of rent.

I already rented another flat, so I wont be staying eitherway.

The tricky part,

On my contract there is a clause that says I need to give 2 months notice - which I failed to notice -  regardless of leaving on the end of the fixed term or not, I was doing research online and came across this [Shelter Webpage](https://england.shelter.org.uk/legal/housing_options/private_rented_accommodation/unfair_terms_and_consumer_law/unfair_terms_and_implied_conditions#_ednref12)

It basically says that this is unfair term on contract, its stated as a example in the unfair terms.

Am I liable for those two months ?

Thank you

Comment: "renovating": do you mean renewing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to give a months notice to LL at the end of a six months contract?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/do-i-need-to-give-a-months-notice-to-ll-at-the-end-of-a-six-months-contract)

Comment: yes sorry, I meant renewing. 

Oh, I looked and couldnt find that answer, it seems to be the same situation. And based on the same information I found online.

Eitherway I have given a months notice, and linked that to the landlord. Lets hope for the best.

Comment: The common law position is cited by shelter in two rather old cases and doesn't rely on statutory unfair contract term provisions. No notice is required to leave at the end of the fixed term and insisting on it is wrong and unenforcable.